# How do i access and alter the default scheduler codes in kubernetes. Not having a custom scheduler

Tags: kubernetes

I installed kubernetes and would like to make a little modification to the default scheduler. I want to know how to access the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kubernetes codebase is at **https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes**

It's written in GO and you can fork the project and start modifying it as you want.

Comment: I have cloned the project and have a go working environment. How do i access the codes on my mac and linux vm to which i cloned the repo?

Comment: Once you clone the project on github, you need to install git on your laptop and 'git clone' your forked project. 
If you need to learn git, you'll find very well done tutorial on youtube. It only takes 1-2 hours to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the codes regarding kubernetes scheduling are [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/scheduler)